# Pull value from <li> in to <textarea> when <li> is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` inside a form that needs to populate with the text inside the `li` tag that a user clicks.

**For example:**

```
<ul id="selections">
    // row1 <li>Here is some text</li>
    // row 2 <li>Here is some more text</li>
    // row 3 <li>Here is even more text</li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks row 1, I need the text to pop in to the textarea. When a user clicks row 2 now, I need row 2 to pop in the textarea, undernieth row 1.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#selections li').click(function() {
  $('#id-of-your-textarea').append($(this).text() + '\n');
})
```

Comment: That works, but it's replacing whatever I had in there last. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's adding to the textarea fine. I'm sure he could tweak it to append. But as of right now, the functionality I'm seeking is not fully there.

Comment: oh ya, he's got it. your wording in the ? was unclear. good job @user1846192

Comment: I have edited the answer to append and add a new line character.

Comment: Sorry about not phrasing it right. Great job, works perfect! I'll make sure to select this as the correct answer in 4 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like below, It will help you...

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/155/

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="selections">
     <li>Here is some text</li>
     <li>Here is some more text</li>
     <li>Here is even more text</li>
</ul>

<textarea id="txtData"></textarea>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$('#selections li').click(function(){    
    $('#txtData').val($('#txtData').val() + "\n" + $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selections").children().each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $("#area").text($("#area").text() + $(this).html() + '\n');
        });
    });
});
</script>

<textarea id="area"></textarea>

<ul id="selections">
    <li>Here is some text</li>
    <li>Here is some more text</li>
    <li>Here is even more text</li>
</ul>
```